# I need to hide reply-box when i press a bootstrap class button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('reply-button');
let crdbody = document.getElementById('card-body');
let replybox = document.getElementById('reply-box');
let cancel = document.getElementById('btn btn-danger');

btn.onclick = function() {
  replybox.style.display = "contents";
}
cancel.onclick = function() {
  crdbody.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="reply-button">Răspunde</button>
    <div id="reply-box" class="card" style="display: none">
        <div class="card-body">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Postează răspunsul</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Renunță</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is, how do i hide all replybox  when i press this bootstrap class button(btn btn-danger) - renunta(cancel)

Comment: <button class="btn" id="reply-button">Răspunde</button>
        <div id="reply-box" class="card" style="display: none">
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Postează răspunsul</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Renunță</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Edit your question with this html code

Answer (score 0):

Your classes/id are errorous:

- `card-body` is actually a class but youre using it as an id
- id `reply-button` never appears in your html
- id `cancel-button` never appears on your html
- using `document.getElementById('btn btn-danger')` doesnt work you need to put an id in there, not multiple classes.

Heres your fixed code:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('reply-button');
let crdbody = document.getElementById('card-body');
let replybox = document.getElementById('reply-box');
let cancel = document.getElementById('cancel-button');

btn.onclick = function() {
  replybox.style.display = "contents";
}
cancel.onclick = function() {
  crdbody.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="reply-box" class="card">
  <div id="card-body">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="reply-button">Postează răspunsul</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel-button">Renunță</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please be aware that `display: contents;` is working draft css (see https://caniuse.com/?search=display%3Acontents and https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/) which means it still may be subject to change and isnt a real standard yet, so you shouldnt (yet) rely on that feature in your actual production code.

**Update since you cant change the HTML:**

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('reply-button');
let replybox = document.getElementById('reply-box');
let cancel = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-danger');

btn.onclick = function() {
  replybox.style.display = "contents";
}
cancel.onclick = function() {
  replybox.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="reply-button">Răspunde</button>
<div id="reply-box" class="card" style="display: none">
  <div class="card-body">
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Postează răspunsul</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Renunță</button> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When selecting elements by classes you can use `document.querySelector` (for single elements) and `document.querySelectorAll` (for multiple elements).

Also note that i removed the `crdbody` variable and changed the script to hide/show the `replybox` so it properly opens/closes multiple times.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say that i can t edit html code. im at an javascript course. and i forgot to mention the button 
<button class="btn" id="reply-button">Răspunde</button>

Comment: @bigwall i updated my answer to make it run without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need this result?

```js
let btn=document.querySelector('#reply-box .btn.btn-primary');
let replybox=document.getElementById('reply-box');
let cancel=document.querySelector('#reply-box .btn.btn-danger');
btn.onclick=function(){
    replybox.style.display="contents";
}
cancel.onclick=function(){
    replybox.style.display="none";
}

btn.click(); // just for testing... it displays the reply box at first time.
```

```html
    <div id="reply-box" class="card" style="display: none">
        <div class="card-body">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Postează răspunsul</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Renunță</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i can't edit html code. i am at an javascript course.